# Numeric overflow on using exponent function

Tags: teradata

I have written a select statement with the exp function to return the exponent of a value. However  an error ie. SELECT Failed.  [2616] Numeric overflow occurred during computation.

The raw number itself is a float type and when I select a few record there are no problems. But when I run it for all records it fails. It obviously has to do with either the exponent not liking the raw values or the resultant exponent violates something.

Comment: I'd look up the table for the largest number and check whether this leads to the overflow. Even a `DOUBLE` is restricted (to numbers up to about 308 digits) and if a result exceeds the possible maximum then you get an error.

Comment: EXP in Teradata may sometimes yield a 2616. The result data type by default is FLOAT. Have you looked at the max value of the column to ensure when EXP is applied the result will fit in a FLOAT (10^306)?